# Find two character pattern, replace only one character

Tags: sed, substitution

In the data below, I want to replace all the commas that are not immediately followed by whitespace with `~`. So the comma in "American President, The (1995)" would remain since there is whitespace immediately after.

```
10,GoldenEye (1995),Action|Adventure|Thriller  
11,"American President, The (1995)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

Here's the output I want:

```
10~GoldenEye (1995)~Action|Adventure|Thriller  
11~"American President, The (1995)"~Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

I've tried the code below, but this replaces two characters instead of just the first one.

```
sed 's/,[^ ]/~/g' file.csv
```

The output I get is below:

```
10~oldenEye (1995)~ction|Adventure|Thriller  
11~American President, The (1995)"~omedy|Drama|Romance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First gsub replaces the commas on first line and the following two sub changes the first and last comma on second line.

```
awk 'NR<2{gsub(/,/,"~")}{sub(/1,/,"1~")}{sub(/,C/,"~C")}1' file
10~GoldenEye (1995)~Action|Adventure|Thriller 
11~"American President, The (1995)"~Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sed 's/,\([^ \t]\)/~\1/g' file.csv`
This gives you the requested output.

Note that this will not replace a trailing comma, so technically it's only a partial solution.
I know sed can do exactly what you've asked, but I don't know how.

If you don't need to convert trailing commas anyway then it doesn't matter.

What this does is finds `,[^ \t]` which is a comma followed by a character that is not a space or a tab. The `'\(` and `\)` can be used to "remember" what was matched, and then value matched by first set of `'\(...\)` can be referenced as `\1`. The second set can be referenced as \2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/,(\S|$)/~\1/g;ta' file
```

This replaces all `,`'s followed by a non-space character or the end-of-file.

N.B. the substitution is in two possible passes to include adjacent `,`'s

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you never have 2 consecutive commas:

```
$ sed -r 's/,([^[:blank:]]|$)/~\1/g' file
10~GoldenEye (1995)~Action|Adventure|Thriller
11~"American President, The (1995)"~Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

or:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/,(\S|$)/,"~\\1","g")}1' file
10~GoldenEye (1995)~Action|Adventure|Thriller
11~"American President, The (1995)"~Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

If you can have multiple consecutive commas then I'd stick with awk:

```
$ awk '{ while( $0!=($0=gensub(/,(\S|$)/,"~\\1","g")) ); }1' file
10~GoldenEye (1995)~Action|Adventure|Thriller
11~"American President, The (1995)"~Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

Here's what happens with both approaches if/when you have consecutive commas:

```
$ echo 'a,,b' | sed -r 's/,([^[:blank:]]|$)/~\1/g'
a~,b

$ echo 'a,,b' | awk '{$0=gensub(/,(\S|$)/,"~\\1","g")}1'
a~,b

$ echo 'a,,b' | awk '{ while( $0!=($0=gensub(/,(\S|$)/,"~\\1","g")) ); }1'
a~~b
```

The above uses GNU awk for `gensub()` so I also used `\S` instead of `[^[:blank]]` since the solution requires GNU awk so also using `\S` does not itself sacrifice portability. If you use GNU sed it will also support `\S` instead of `[^[:blank:]]`, idk about other seds. With other awks it'd be:

```
awk '{ while( i=match($0,/,([^[:blank:]]|$)/) ) $0=substr($0,1,i-1)"~"substr($0,i+1) } 1'
```